# Django page not reloading when files change

Tags: python, django

I use a Django library called "django-livesync" https://github.com/fabiogibson/django-livesync
I'm working from home now (you know, coronavirus) and everything works fine in my django project but when I change some file the page is not reloading.

In my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'livesync',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'livesync.core.middleware.DjangoLiveSyncMiddleware'
]

DEBUG = True
```

Something must be working because when I check the chrome console I see this object:

[image]

Do you guys have any clue of why this isn't reloading the page when there's a change?